# jQuery ajax querying a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Testing AJAX</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function init() {
        $("#form1").submit(submitForm);
    }

    function submitForm() {
        var paramValue = $("#param_input").val();

        $.ajax({  
                type: "GET", 
                url: 'http//xxx.edu/xxx/autocomplete.php', 
                data: {
                    query: paramValue
                },  
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function(data){  
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
                }  
        }); 
    }

    // On page load
    $(document).ready(init);

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1_name" action="" >
<label for="find">Value</label>
<input type="text" name="param" id="param_input" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Find">  
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I really want to be able to query my PHP script (which returns a `JSON` via `json_encode()`) and use that `JSON` information.

Right now the alert box says this:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

So I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas? I'm all new to AJAX / jQuery.

**EDIT**: added dataType: "json" but that did not help - still returning wrong JSON stuff...

Comment: Is the call to a same-origin script, i.e is the script being ran on the same server as the one that creates the page which calls $.ajax?

Comment: did you verify (in firebug, fiddler, ...) if the php script returns valid/any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use success in place of complete, as in success callback you will get your data. In complete you will get XHR object

Refer below script

```
function submitForm() {
    var paramValue = $("#param_input").val();

    $.ajax({  
            type: "GET", 
            url: 'http//xxx.edu/xxx/autocomplete.php', 
            data: {
                query: paramValue
            },  
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){  
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            }  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: when I use `success` I get nothing (the alert doesn't come up) as opposed to the wrong alert..

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a `dataType` param to jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

For example:

```
    $.ajax({  
            type: "GET", 
            url: 'http//xxx.edu/xxx/autocomplete.php', 
            data: {
                query: paramValue
            },  
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(data){  
                console.log( data ); 
            }  
    });
```

One of the benefits of jQuery's ajax interface is that you won't have to `JSON.parse` (or worse, `eval`) if you use the correct `dataType` flag.

Comment: Are you trying to do this across domains? domain, protocol (http/s) and port all need to match in most cases to comply with the same-origin policy. What is the status code of the response?

Comment: nope, my domain. also when using the syntax url: `../xxx/autocomplete.php`, the same behavior occurs. status (as you can see above) is 0. don't know how to see the HTTP status. using `console.log(data)` shows `
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.` so I don't know what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there just add [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your $.ajax call.

```
function submitForm() {
    var paramValue = $("#param_input").val();

    $.ajax({  
            type: "GET", 
            url: 'http//xxx.edu/xxx/autocomplete.php', 
            data: {
                query: paramValue
            },  
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data){  
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            }  
    }); 
}
```

Alternatively you can declare the return content to be json by declaring it within the http response header.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

You would use the above if you were restricted to vanilla JS, it is possibly good practice to use it anyway.

Comment: That is the only prevalent error in your code. What is the output when of complete if you use console.log(), string, object etc?

Comment: using `console.log(data)` shows `Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.` so I don't know what is going on...

Comment: It sounds like you're output isn't being recognised as json. Try putting the above php headers into your file, if they don't force it to be interpreted as json try prepending something like "data = " to your json_encode() call. Final, possibly insulting, question: are you remembering to "echo json_encode();" and not just calling the encode function?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to also send JSON data, then you have to stringify already the data sent to the server.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET", 
    url: 'http//xxx.edu/xxx/autocomplete.php', 
    data: JSON.stringify({
        query: paramValue
    }),  
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(data){  
        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    }  
});
```

you should add this javascript file to make sure the JSON parser exists:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cross domain call which will fail unless you use Jsonp or some hacks. You should look for hacks for cross domain call to work something like YQL

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/

Comment: nope it's my domain. also when using the syntax `url: '../xxx/autocomplete.php',` the same behavior occurs